# Calling Fragment within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am calling 2nd fragment from 1st fragment and inflating a layout with 2 fragment when its calls second fragment the layout of the first fragment also appears on the screen behind the second fragment layout. i want to show only 2nd layout on the screen. 
here is the code

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                facebookPictureShareFragment Picfragment = new facebookPictureShareFragment();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                 ft.add(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), Picfragment);
                 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);

                 ft.commit();
```

Comment: you Just replace the fragment. ft.replace();

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ft.add to ft.replace.

> add() adds a fragment to the activity state.

replace()

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Comment: ((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId() is it the same container you are replacing inside your fragment. WHy aint you using the id of the view you are trying to replace. like (R.id.containder_id)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Callbacks and insert this code into your activity not inside the Fragment, check this link for more details:

[Android Fragments Callback](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

If you are displaying one fragment at a time, Google recommends to use one fragment for one activity and use the fragment as a container. Using the EventCallbacks approach keeps the activity very simple and you can then add or remove fragments to it much simpler.